# Alternative log in & authentication methods (for elderly people)

Tags: php, zend-framework, authentication

I'm designing a simple web app for some elderly family members, 1 of whom has Alzheimer's. The end goal is to provide them each with a tablet (probably Android but irrelevant for this problem) that would be stripped down to ideally 1 bookmark on the home screen which opens my web app.

What I am looking for are ideas on how to identify the user without the conventional username/password methods. With their condition I know that remembering an username is going to be almost impossible, let alone a password. Ideally I would recognize the device and relate that to a specific user.

There will be other users on the app that access it through normal methods (username+password on PC/mobile/tablet), which I'm handling with Zend_Auth. It's just these 2 users who I am concerned about identifying.

Security isn't a huge concern as the data will not be sensitive in any way, but I still need to differentiate between users.

I am building this in php with Zend Framework. I'm really looking for more ideas than specific code, although anything based in php or javascript would be great. Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your help

Comment: (+1, spiritually) I would upvote this if I hadn't reached my daily voting limit

Comment: Maybe a browser plugin that authenticates to the server based on private/public key pair or using some kind of hardware attribute specifics like a MAC address or something?

Comment: Thanks SC. 

@prodigitalson MAC address was my first thought but it doesn't appear to be possible unless you are on the same local network, which won't be the case. And (like most eldery I assume) they don't have dedicated IP so I can't go that route. I'm lucky enough that they aren't on dial-up...

Comment: Shouldnt each NIC have a unique MAC address on the hardware (ie. manuf. assigned and network independent), assuming they arent being spoofed? Im saying to use a browser plugin to auth them which would have the ability to read the hardware directly from the OS and then set a cookie ro some other flag storing mechanism. You could also look at using a client side DB data store for the credentials... Ive actually been using it recently on project that runs on webkit. Uberwierd to be writing sql queries and prepared statements in JS but it works :-)

Comment: MAC addresses are only used on the local network segment. They are not retained through routing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These advice are only valuable if security is not an issue :

- On the bookmarks page, insert a token in the link, which you will use to authenticate the users.
- if you can, check in the background for IP/user agent (if there is only one device that needs this simplified auth process, and assuming it's connection uses a fixed IP address)

And a simple idea if you have multiple users using the same device :

- on your bookmark page, put a picture of each user
- make it clickable, with the token discussed above in the href of the link.

That's simple to implement and easy to remember.

Hope that helps !